# Positive Lookbehind With Quantifiers

Tags: regex, r, awk, sed

I am trying to change some XML tags in a file to make them easier to read into R, but some of the tags are the same, which xmlToDataFrame does not seem to like. See below:

```
<DATE calender="Western">1996-06-22</DATE>
<DATE calender="Persian">1375/04/02</DATE>
<CAT xml:lang="fa">ادب و هنر</CAT>
<CAT xml:lang="en">Literature and Art</CAT>
```

I'm trying to rename some of the tags using regular expressions so that it looks more like this:

```
<DATE_Western>1996-06-22</DATE_Western>
<DATE_Persian>1375/04/02</DATE_Persian>
<CAT_Persian>ادب و هنر</CAT_Persian>
<CAT_English>Literature and Art</CAT_English>
```

I tried using a positive lookbehind, but I would need some kind of quantifiers to capture after the inside of the tags and that doesn't seem to be supported by many regex implementations.

Any suggestions?

Also, what is the best command line tool for doing search and replace on a large number of files (sed, awk?)

Thanks!

Comment: lookbehinds does not support quantifiers, instead you can use \K

Comment: Any ideas on how you'd convert `<CAT xml:lang="fa">` to `<CAT_Persian>`? Do you have a mapping table in a file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    map["fa"]="Persian"
    map["en"]="English"
}
{
    for (abbr in map)
        $0 = gensub("(xml:lang=\")" abbr "(\")","\\1" map[abbr] "\\2","")
    $0 = gensub(/(<[^[:space:]]+)[^"]+"([^"]+)">(.*)>$/,"\\1_\\2>\\3_\\2>","")
}
1' file
<DATE_Western>1996-06-22</DATE_Western>
<DATE_Persian>1375/04/02</DATE_Persian>
<CAT_Persian>ادب و هنر</CAT_Persian>
<CAT_English>Literature and Art</CAT_English>
```

Comment: Hi Ed...sorry, I think I made the mistake of asking two questions at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without lookbehinds, simply perform a substitution.

#### Regex

```
<(\w+)[^"]*"(.*?)">(.*?)<\/\1>
```

#### Replacement

```
<\1_\2>\3</\1_\2>
```

#### Example

http://regex101.com/r/kM0rA4

Comment: he wants it to be   
  **<DATE_Western>1996-06-22</DATE_Western>** 
so it would be <\1_\2>\3</\1_\2>

Comment: He also wants to translate `<CAT xml:lang="fa">` to `<CAT_Persian>`.

Comment: @EdMorton , I'm only showing that it can be done, not providing the entire solution :) the matches would need to be split up. No point in doing a one-line regex for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sed` command also,

```
sed '/ xml\:lang\=\"fa\"/ s/fa/Persian/g; / xml\:lang\=\"en\"/ s/en/English/g; s|^<\(.*\) .*="\(.*\)">\(.*\)<\(.*\)>|<\1_\2>\3<\4_\2>|g' file
```

Output:

```
<DATE_Western>1996-06-22</DATE_Western>
<DATE_Persian>1375/04/02</DATE_Persian>
<CAT_Persian>ادب و هنر</CAT_Persian>
<CAT_English>Literature and Art</CAT_English>
```